# Why is there distortion for the same two geoJSON features with different base maps?

Tags: javascript, postgis, geojson, map-projections

When displaying two features, a polygon `a` (see [geoJSON](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ktraff/45dae43d750886b88541/raw/2ed8feb9e0d91bbecebf6d3225f285b1ecf63d7e/gistfile1.txt)) and its minimum bounding rectangle `b` (see [geoJSON](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ktraff/28af6e671d070d0ebb0d/raw/25549f0380710d668981524cfee2ef7c7f90c0ab/gistfile1.txt)), I get the [following result](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ac09cb6f105d514ef768) when viewing from geojson.io:

[image]

The minimum bounding rectangle around the polygon looks more like a parallelogram than a rectangle to me.

However, when I upload these same features to OpenLayers, the distortion is gone:

[image]

Is this a projection issue?

Comment: Yes it looks like a projection issue... what projection are you using for the GeoJSON? are you using topojson/d3?

Comment: Yes indeed that appears to be due to different map projections for the base map and OpenLayers. If you make them same/similar, that distortion will disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GeoJON shown on GitHub is projected using a [Spherical Mercator](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/spherical_mercator.html) projection. This done automatically is so it can overlay with other web-mapped data (e.g. I can see it is in Colorado).

The second image is a Cartesian projection of raw coordinate data, so it is not projected. So the bounding box preserves it's right angles.